# UIImageView Asset set with a blue line in production iOS13

Tags: ios, swift

I’m using an asset as an image of a `UIImageView` component in each one of my `UITableViewCells`. For some reason the asset is replaced with a square and a thick blue border.

This only happens on production from the `AppStore` and devices running iOS 13. Can not replicate when running from Xcode.

[Production - device running iOS 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Pcm.png)

[Production - device running below iOS 13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT9o1.png)

Comment: What is the FORMAT of your image? i.e. .png ?

Comment: Please provide more information: your image asset, .json file for this image asset and `UIImageView` configuration

Comment: you can do Product | Archive | Distribute | Development to get the same behaviour as if downloaded from the app store.

Comment: The format of the image is .png